# Cannot read property 'options' of null javascript in wordpress snippet

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am doing `selectedIndex.text` to get the text value from select options but keep on getting error as 'Cannot read property 'options' of null' . This code is work perfectly in localhost but in wordpress server it did not.

```
function hideunit_hookjavascript() {
    ?>
    <script>
 /*window.onload = function() {
            var ownselect_property = document.getElementById("pods-form-ui-pods-field-listing-property-type");
            ownselect_property.addEventListener("input", mypropertyFunction);
 }*/
            
    (function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here


        
            var myfieldSelect = document.getElementById("pods-form-ui-pods-field-listing-property-type");
            var mychoice = myfieldSelect.options[myfieldSelect.selectedIndex].text;
            // const myunit_type_field = document.querySelector('#pods-form-ui-pods-field-unit-type');
            var tempp = mychoice.trim();
                if (tempp == 'Land' || tempp == 'Agriculture Land' || tempp == 'Commercial Land' || tempp == 'Industrial Land' || tempp == 'Residential Land') {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("pods-form-ui-row-name-unit-type")[0].style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementsByClassName("pods-form-ui-row-name-unit-entrance-direction")[0].style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementsByClassName("pods-form-ui-row-name-unit-length")[0].style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementsByClassName("pods-form-ui-row-name-unit-width")[0].style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementsByClassName("pods-form-ui-row-name-unit-built-area")[0].style.display = "none";
        
                } else {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("pods-form-ui-row-name-unit-type")[0].style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementsByClassName("pods-form-ui-row-name-unit-entrance-direction")[0].style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementsByClassName("pods-form-ui-row-name-unit-length")[0].style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementsByClassName("pods-form-ui-row-name-unit-width")[0].style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementsByClassName("pods-form-ui-row-name-unit-built-area")[0].style.display = "block";
                }
        })();
 
</script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'hideunit_hookjavascript');
```